# Intellij doc preview prevent new line at param

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

I have this

[image]

The table jump automatically on new line.

I could prevent to auto jump on new line? Or this is just from Intellij?

My expectation

[image]

Comment: Hi @KunLun, could you describe your expactation?
With <tr> a new table row is generated. So it is naturally that a new line is created. Just dont use <table> at all or only one row. I am not sure if I get your Question right. Pls. provide more information.

Comment: @hce Hi! I edited my post.

Comment: @KunLun request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @KunLun, thanks for the clarification. That really is an interesting question. I am afraid, its to hard to solve for me. I would suggest to keep your JavaDoc comments simple. If you want to use some html code to do your formatting, make sure your JavaDoc is created appropriately. Anyhow, you can request this at youtrack as CrazyCoder stated. best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you wanted, but if you dont mind repeating your paramname, then you can do the following:

```
 * @param options Customized ChromeOptions<br>
 *        options &#8211; null for new <i>ChromeOptions()</i>
```

[image]

I couldnt find any better solution.